# Centos Linux, слишком много места

Tags: linux, centos, digitalocean

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, почему когда я делаю Snapshot на DigitalOcean, это что-то типа бэкапа, показывается размер 5.22 GB

Но когда я захожу в mc и делаю сортировку по кол-ву занятого места, в общем выходит 3.6 гига (см. скрин), что не  так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот результат df -h

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каком формате backup? Это на 95% и будет ответом на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Ещё вы упустили из виду примерно Гбайт на синеньком экране.

Comment: `du -h /path` вам в помощь. А еще почитайте про файловые системы, они умеют как уменьшать размер данных сжатием, так и увеличивать занимаемый размер на диске (1000 файлов по 1 байту занимает не обязательно 1000 байт на жестком диске, к примеру). Сравнивать полезный размер файлов и занимаемое место на жестком диске не корректно, это разные метрики, в разных величинах. Как кислое с красным сравнивать.